# How to create object as parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the foloowing snippet:

```
function click(...actions: any) { 
  const [ a, b, c ] = actions;
  console.log(b);
}

let a = {
  show: [
    1, 2, 3, this.addService
  ]
};

click(a.show);
```

So, I try to add some variables in object `a` by key `show`.

Then I want to get these parameters and pass to function click().

Then in function `click` I attempted to get all parameters in variables `[ a, b, c ]`.

My problem is in:

```
show: [1, 2, 3, this.addService]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that I don know how to pass object as parameters in function, where properties of object is it varaibles and functons, services

Comment: Just don't spread the parameter in the argument list.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank  you!

Comment: You could still make this dynamic and take any number of arguments and have the last arg always be a function and then call that function with the rest of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform destructing of array data.

```js
function click([a,b,c]) { 
  console.log(a, b, c);
}

let a = {
  show: [
    1, 2, 3, this.addService
  ]
};

click(a.show);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the spread operator from the function argument.

```
function click(actions: any) { 
  const [ a, b, c ] = actions;
  console.log(b);
}

let a = {
  show: [
    1, 2, 3, this.addService
  ]
};

click(a.show);
```